# What does it mean by the Probability Measure on T?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

What does the following statement mean?

> Suppose that $X$ is a random variable for the experiment, taking values in a set $T$.
>   The function $B↦P(X∈B)$ defines a probability measure on $T$.

Let,

$Experiment$ = a dice rolls.

$\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

- What are the element of $T$?
- Is $B$ a function of a set?
- What would be the elements of set $B$?
- What does it mean by $X∈B$?
- What does the symbol $↦$ represent?

Comment: Do you know anything about measure theory? Or at least sigma fields/borel sigma field?

Comment: @GiantTortoise1729, No. I am only studying Introduction to Probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the following statement mean?
>
> > Suppose that $X$ is a random variable for the experiment, taking values in a set $T$.

$T$ is a set of values the random variable can realise; it is the support of the random variable $X$.   In the case of your dice toss experiment, that is the set of results: $T=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

> > The function $B\mapsto P(X\in B)$ defines a probability measure on $T$.

There is some function, let us say $f$, which maps sets of values (call it $B$) to the probability that the random variable realises one of the elements of that set, $P(X\in B)$ .   That is, we define $f(B):=P(X\in B)$.

In the case of your dice toss experiment: $P(X\in B)=\dfrac{\lvert B\cap T\rvert}{\lvert T\rvert}$.

For example: $$f(\{1,2,4,6\}) = \frac 46$$

Answer (score 1):

T in this context is equivalent to the elements of $\Omega$. $B$ describes the space of possibilities being described. If you want to know what the probability of rolling a 1,2 or 3 is, then

$$ B = \{1,2,3\} $$

$$ P(X \in B) $$

Refers to the probability that the independent variable $x$ takes on a value in $B$. In this context, the probability that $x$ (your outcome from the roll) is one of the values in $B$.

Comment: In case of coin toss, T = {1, 0} right?

Comment: Yeah. You're really using $\Omega$ and T interchangeably here ... stick to one of them. T = {1,0} or {H,T} whatever you like.

Comment: can you give me a simple example where $\Omega$ and $T$ can be different?

Comment: Nope, haha. What I'm saying is you're calling the set of possibilities A and then calling it B. They're the same thing. Either call it $\Omega$ or call it T.